# network monitoring

Tags: sniffing

i made use of libcap package(which includes pcap) for my sniffing program. Now, i want to extend my project by adding network monitoring/processing capabilities. As in, i should be able to make use of the sniffed data and take some decisions and implement in the program. I am making use of C language. Any idea about how to procede?? Please help me..
Thanks you all :):)

Answer (score 0):

Use snmp (simple network management protocol) to monitor and manage your network resources. There are snmp libraries in C.